# JQuery Looping Hide/Show

Tags: jquery, loops, toggle

I'm creating a dashboard site with drill down capabilities using +/- icons to hide/show categories/subcategories/subsubcategories etc.

I'm trying to make the site dynamically driven so that regardless of the number of categories/subcategories, the script will function without knowing its exact ID.

I know just enough about JQuery to be dangerous and I'm unfortunately under a time crunch and was hoping an expert may be able to point me in the right direction.

---

I have X Categories, each with X Subcategories, each with X SubSubCategories. The Categories and Subcategories need to have the ability to be toggled on/off to hide/show whatever is under them.

I'd like to be able to use the following code to handle any Category/Subcatery hide/show functionality dynamically.  All of my data to populate the dashboard will be coming from a database and new categories/subcategories could be added at any time.

Any Ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".subsub").hide();
$(".subsubsub").hide();

$("#togglecat1").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#HScat1").attr("src") == "filter_hide.gif"){ 
        $("#HScat1").attr("src", "filter_reveal.gif"); }
    else{ $("#HScat1").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif"); }

    $(".cat1").toggle();
    $(".subsubsub").hide();
    $("#HScat1sub1").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif");
    $("#HScat1sub2").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif");
    $("#HScat1sub3").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif");

});

$("#togglecat1sub1").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#HScat1sub1").attr("src") == "filter_hide.gif"){ 
        $("#HScat1sub1").attr("src", "filter_reveal.gif"); }
    else{ $("#HScat1sub1").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif"); }

    $(".cat1sub1").toggle();

});
$("#togglecat1sub2").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#HScat1sub2").attr("src") == "filter_hide.gif"){ 
        $("#HScat1sub2").attr("src", "filter_reveal.gif"); }
    else{ $("#HScat1sub2").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif"); }

    $(".cat1sub2").toggle();

});
$("#togglecat1sub3").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#HScat1sub3").attr("src") == "filter_hide.gif"){ 
        $("#HScat1sub3").attr("src", "filter_reveal.gif"); }
    else{ $("#HScat1sub3").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif"); }

    $(".cat1sub3").toggle();

});


$("#togglecat2").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if($("#HScat2").attr("src") == "filter_hide.gif"){ 
        $("#HScat2").attr("src", "filter_reveal.gif"); }
    else{ $("#HScat2").attr("src", "filter_hide.gif"); }

    $(".cat2").toggle();
});
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTyWv/4/#&togetherjs=eUHaDqo6fv)

Comment: Provide a HTML sample/jsFiddle please

Comment: One standard practice is to simply render as nested `ULs` with `LIs` per item/ subcategory and let the jQuery manage all visibility & click issues. This is the way most jQuery menu plugins work. Is this an option for you? You certainly do not want any hard-wired click events on specific items. A sample of your HTML would be useful (preferably in a JSFiddle)

Comment: One other thing I forgot to add, which I don't have in the demo is that a total of 7 columns that will be dependent on the Categories Subcategories displaying data for each day of the week, so I'll need to hide/show their respective rows as well (I would assume using the hide/show on a specific CLASS name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of classes, data attributes, and jQuery selectors, this below code can dynamically create sublevels automagically (even though they are in actuality siblings) and functions to enable them to be manually expanded/contracted.

I put together this [demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/ta4QT/3/). Here is the js:

```
$(function () {
    var hide_src = "http://www.synchronizeddesigns.com/filter_hide.gif",
        reveal_src = "http://www.synchronizeddesigns.com/filter_reveal.gif";

    $('[class^="sub"]').hide();

    $('.category, .sub').each(function () {
        if ($(this).next('[class^="sub"]').length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("expandable")
            .find('td:first')
                .prepend('<img class="pre plus" src="' + hide_src + '" />');
        }
    });

    $('.expandable').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var $t = $("#" + e.delegateTarget.id),
            $i = $($t).find('img');

        var $s = $i.attr('src') == hide_src ? reveal_src : hide_src;
        $i.attr("src", $s);

        var $l = $t.parent()
            .find("[data-parent='" + e.delegateTarget.id + "']")
            .fadeToggle();

        var subs = $('#' + e.delegateTarget.id + 
                     '~ tr[data-parent^="' + e.delegateTarget.id + '_"]');

        if (subs.is(':visible')) {
            subs.fadeOut();
            $i = $($l).find('img');
            $s = $i.attr('src') == hide_src ? reveal_src : hide_src;
            $i.attr("src", $s);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is close for a 1 column view. Is there a way to have the SubSub's to not be expanded, by default, when the Subcategory is expanded. Also, there will be 7 columns looping each days worth of data and I'm not sure if the nested DIVs may work.

Row Names(Cats/Sub/SubSub) | Sun | Mon | Tues | Weds | etc.

The data will be pulled by day in a loop so I was doing a table inside a floating DIV for each... so I would need to do hide/show's on all rows for each date dependent on whether the Cat/SubCats are expanded.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out.

Comment: Good, because I was puzzling over this for the last hour. :) I've made a few updates to your fiddle, but I'm still 100% on how to implement all of your requirements.

Comment: I Updated the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTyWv/4/#&togetherjs=eUHaDqo6fv) again with the most recent code. If you can think of any way of streamlining it any more, I'd appreciate it. Again, I know just enough to be deadly. My code is relying heavily on naming conventions, but at least I can control them when the different rows are created.

Comment: Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/nTyWv/5/) with a few refactored lines. My only remaining issue with your solution is the number of individual rows being generated. It seems a little excessive to create a tr and td for each cell. Each row should contain as many td's as you have th's (headings). I'm still putting together another fiddle to fix this and incorporate your additional requirements.

Comment: There's one more thing that I see. If you expand all the subs under Category 2, then Expand Category 1, it's collapsing the Cat 2 subs. Is there a way around this?

There's a ton of more data that goes into this dashboard, this is just the first portion. It doesn't have to be in tables, but this code is going into a CMS that actually uses JellyScript so I know it was playing nice with tables.

Comment: @patlxix9 I wasn't able to replicate that issue... It doesn't collapse any other groupings other than the one clicked. Here's my [final updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/ta4QT/3/). It is much more simplified and it appears [to me] that it meets all of your requirements as well as solves the issues you were reporting. I tried to move this to chat, but there was some error... Feel free to chat instead so we can avoid extending this comment section.

Comment: Your demo looks like everything is working, however, I'm concerned on how I am going to display the data. A days worth of data will be pulled and displayed through a loop, then moved on to the next days worth of data. Now that everything is in 1 large table instead of single tables, I'm not sure how to display this w/o a ton of logic.

Comment: Without knowing what the dataset you're using looks like, I can't offer much help. If you're already using jQuery to loop through the data, it would be extremely simple to tell it how to populate and where to go (ie. which TR to be appended to). You yourself saw how I was able to reduce your 100+ lines of code down to ~30. Putting everything in a single table is almost always the more-correct way in my opinion.

Comment: Unfortunately we're using JellyScript to populate the data. I think that if I can get the drawers to close on the version of JsFiddle I last posted I might be ok. I know it's probably not the most efficient, but it fits with what was previously working. (The client wants to be able to select how many days to show, so it will be defaulted to 7 days, but will potentially show a months worth of data.

Comment: Then that sounds like material for another StackOverflow post since your original question seems to have a working solution. I'm glad that I could help at least a little bit! Feel free to upvote my response or choose it as the answer, or post your own solution as another answer so that others may benefit as well.

Comment: you've been a big help. Yes, you provided an example that does what I was asking for, however, I do not think I can do with it what I'll need to due the way the program will loop out it's data. Would you be able to assist in getting my last fiddle to open/close all drawers properly? I'm assuming I'll need to close based on category class.. but I'm sure there's probably a quicker solution w/o reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @patlxix9 Here's the best I could do. http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/nTyWv/6/ I added comments to explain my logic, but it was actually quite difficult to get the collapsing to work if multiple levels were open. My first solution would have made this much simpler but given the structure you had decided on, I did what I could. There is one bug I could not resolve: if a menu is opened two levels deep, on collapse all elements are hidden but the category img src is not changed so it displays opposite of what it should. This was a minor issue and I think you can tackle it :)

Comment: Thanks again for all of your hard work. You truly are a lifesaver. I've been looking at your other version trying to figure out how to use jQuery to populate the tables columns first. I'm seeing similar posts about it, just need to figure that out. I'll certainly look at your new jsFiddle and see what I can do regarding the images. Thanks again!